# Ger chassidus teachings

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, mysticism-kabbalah, chasidut-hasidism

Does the community know what defines Ger chasiduss ideologically and Hashkafically? Is there an English translated sefarim or article that explains the basics of the Hasidic dynasty’s teachings?

Comment: https://torah.org/series/sfas-emes/ https://ben-tzion.com/category/chidushei-harim/